# Drools Fusion Conversion to long not supported from java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, drools, drools-fusion, complex-event-processing, zoneddatetime

I am trying to use the Drools Fusion temporal operators *before, after,* and *coincides* but I keep getting the error:

> Conversion to long not supported from java.time.ZonedDateTime

In my objects, the times I am comparing are ZonedDateTime. Does Drools require time variables be a specific type? What does the error mean by conversion to long?

I have tried using .isBefore() and .isAfter() but it seems Drools does not recognize these functions.

Comment: Drools is happy if it can compare long values resulting from java.util.getTime(). You might have to add a getter to your fact class returning that, converted from the ZonedDateTime.

Answer (score 1):

From Drools version 7.0.0.Beta8 it is possible to use CEP temporal operators using *also* `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, along with broader `java.time` support.

You can find more details about temporal operators to support for `java.time` classes here: [DROOLS-1490](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1490), until the v7 Final release will come out with documentation release notes.